# Why doesn't VS 2013 Express allow inspection of AggregateException?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a simple TPL+async/await program that I would like to debug:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = ThrowException().Result;
    }

    async static Task<int> ThrowException()
    {
        throw new Exception("I want this Exception to be shown when the debugger breaks");
    }
}
```

The behavior I want is for the debugger to break when the Exception is observed, and I want to have access to the message ("I want this Exception...") via inspection of AggregateException's InnerException.  In Visual Studio 2013 Premium, I get exactly the behavior I want:

[image]

But, Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop behaves as if some un-debuggable component produced the Exception and I can't get any more information about it (for instance, the InnerException with the actual information regarding what went wrong):

[image]

Is this an inherent limitation of VS 2013 Express, or is there some setting I can change to get the correct behavior in Express?  The target framework for the both projects is 4.5.

Comment: IIRC, the express editions didn't have that capability.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "that capability" is?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806898/the-exception-assistant-is-missing-again-in-2013

Comment: I don't think the exception assistant was available in the express editions. They were already very watered down versions of Studio, that feature required other features that just wasn't available/included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by @Hans Passant and @Jeff Mercado in comments on the question, Visual Studio Express 2013 does not have "exception assistant", a feature that is present in Premium 2013 as well as Visual C# 2010 Express (as well as others).  As a result, ALL Exceptions (not just those involving the TPL+async/await features) are shown in an uninformative, ugly, modal box that does not provide access to the properties of the Exception.

More information: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806898/the-exception-assistant-is-missing-again-in-2013

If this is an important feature for you, you can vote to fix it here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5403561-improve-usability-of-the-exception-dialog-in-expre